# How to return an hour: minute string, moved by particular offset?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, momentjs

So I have a date string:

```
const date = '2000-01-01T01:00:00Z';
```

And offset (difference in minutes between the UTC given date and my timezone):

```
const offset = 60;
```

I want to achieve this:

```
02:00
```

So I need to somehow move the time in date by particular number of minutes (the offset) and return only the time in HH:mm format.

I tried to use moment.js and pure JS Date object but the problem is that when I put the `date` into their construction objects, they immediately take my local browser time into account (which I want to ommit). What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment js docs (parse) - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/:

```
moment.utc(...) is utc mode. Ambiguous input is assumed to be UTC. Unambiguous input is adjusted to UTC.
```

Should parse your date in UTC time

Then use function `add` - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

to add your minutes 
and then format - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

```
moment.utc('2000-01-01T01:00:00Z').add(60, 'm').format('h:mm')
```

Comment: I did ```moment.utc(date).add(offset).format('HH:mm')``` and what I achieved is '21:00'. I have the local browser timezone set for 'GMT-0300 (America Montevideo Standard Time)'.

Comment: what is offset and what is date

Comment: After adding 'm' to the ```add``` function arguments (exactly like in the post you edited) I got ```22:00```.
```moment.utc('2000-01-01T01:00:00Z').add(60, 'm').format('HH:mm')```

Comment: Apparently, my local time ('GMT-0300 (America Montevideo Standard Time)') is still taken into account.

Comment: @HubertKubiak it is important that you edit your question and add those codes showing what you've tried, to avoid people answering things that you already done

Comment: weird, because when I execute this line of code - `moment.utc('2000-01-01T01:00:00Z').add(60, 'm').format('HH:mm')` it shows to me 02:00, however I'm in UTC+3. Most probably you need to check time settings on your computer. I can suppose, you just tune clocks for -3 hours without timezone change.

Comment: I just use the Change Timezone plugin for Chrome to manipulate the timezone settings. It just works in the timezone that really is in 60 minutes offset from UTC (like Europe/Copenhagen). In any other timezones, the result is different from expectations.